# Capturing Top 100 Costly queries in SQL Server (<2014)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to capture costly queries daily and save it into a table for further analysis. I am using daily job to do this which runs daily at night.

Using below code to capture costly queries:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CostlyQueries](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QueryText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [execution_count] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [total_logical_reads] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [last_logical_reads] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [total_logical_writes] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [last_logical_writes] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [total_worker_time] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [last_worker_time] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [total_elapsed_time_in_S] [bigint] NULL,
    [last_elapsed_time_in_S] [bigint] NULL,
    [last_execution_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [query_plan] [xml] NULL,
    [DateAdded] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
)


INSERT INTO CostlyQueries (QueryText, execution_count, total_logical_reads, last_logical_reads, total_logical_writes, [last_logical_writes], total_worker_time, last_worker_time
    , total_elapsed_time_in_S, last_elapsed_time_in_S, last_execution_time, query_plan )
SELECT TOP 100 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
    ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
    WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
    ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
    END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1) AS QueryText,
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
    qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
    qs.total_worker_time,
    qs.last_worker_time,
    qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY last_elapsed_time_in_S desc,
qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

Two questions here:

> 1. When these DMV's (system data) refreshed? Somewhere I read it will be refreshed during recycling of sql services. Anyone have details on this?
> 2. Queries I written to capture costly queries uses sys.dm_exec_query_stats, for some reason it did not captured a long running query during weekend. Can anyone help to correct/get more details so that we can capture more metrics?

Added correct query as suggested by Aaron Bertrand in below comments : - Changing cross apply to outer apply -

```
SELECT TOP 100 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
    ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
    WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
    ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
    END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1) AS QueryText,
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
    qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
    qs.total_worker_time,
    qs.last_worker_time,
    qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY last_elapsed_time_in_S desc,
qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data will stay in the DMV as long as the plan is in cache. Plans can be dropped out of the cache for several different reasons (memory pressure, re-compilation etc). In addition all sorts of things like changing settings or restarting the server will of course flush everything.

If you want this to be somewhat reliable, you'll have to run it quite frequently, so that anything important doesn't get lost.

Comment: Also you can change CROSS APPLY to OUTER APPLY so you can still get information about long-running queries even if there is no plan found in the cache.

Comment: Is that mean QueryText and QueryPlan might flushed before query stats?

Comment: @Kannan Sure, query plans can get evicted from the plan cache for all kinds of reasons, and in some cases queries can not register a plan in the cache in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with doing your own analysis as it will always be 100% tailored to your needs, however, I would suggest that you also look into the SQL Server Data Collector and [Data Collection Sets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964725(v=sql.105).aspx).